# undefined reference to `__gcov_dump()

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I try to test the __gcov_dump function via a simple example like this:

tmp.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcov.h>

int main()
{
  int i, total;

  total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    total += i;

  if (total != 45)
    printf ("Failure\n");
   else
    printf ("Success\n");

  __gcov_dump();
}
```

~/Downloads/gcovtest ❯ g++ --coverage -lgcov tmp.c
/tmp/user/ccdEPxlm.o: In function `main': tmp.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to` __gcov_dump()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Leaving out -lgcov makes not difference.

It's an Ubuntu 18.04 LTE with a
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1sav0) 9.4.0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcov.a is present and the program tries to open it as strace says.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I cannot use the standard gcov.h header when using g++. I have to declare the method manually with c linkage:

```
extern "C" void __gcov_dump();
```